# Purpose of MongoCredential

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

Was looking up a tutorial for connecting mongoDb with a java application and found that the were using MongoCredential to create credentials.
What is the purpose of MongoCredential since all they do is print it to the console and is not used elsewhere.
Also the code runs fine without the use of MongoCredential

This is the code i refered to

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase; 
import com.mongodb.MongoClient; 
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;  

public class ConnectToDB { 

public static void main( String args[] ) {  

  // Creating a Mongo client 
  MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 ); 

  // Creating Credentials 
  MongoCredential credential; 
  credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("sampleUser", "myDb", 
     "password".toCharArray()); 
  System.out.println("Connected to the database successfully");  

  // Accessing the database 
  MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("myDb"); 
  System.out.println("Credentials ::"+ credential);     
   } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It work because you are not using any username or password in your **own** database, the minimal configuration to connect is the `host` the `port` and the `database name` and all those you use them in your code.

But for those who use a `username` and `password` they need to specify `MongoCredential` which mean specify the username and password in another word.

Comment: So I could use this            ?                                                                  MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),Arrays.asList(credential))

Comment: yes @Jai you can don't forgot the new in the begging `new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), Arrays.asList(credential))`